# Assign a static IP to an instance in Amazon Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a static website and would like to get data using AJAX from a third-party API. The third-party API needs to add the server IP address to its whitelist to allow me to get the data. For this reason I would need a static IP address for the server.

I would like to use Amazon Amplify, but it doesn't allow adding a static IP address and it seems like I can use only Amazon Lightsail to run server and host a website with a static IP address.

Amazon Lightsail [allows](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-create-static-ip) assigning a static IP address. Is there a way how to assign a static IP address in Amazon Amplify?

Comment: Amplify doesn’t require any servers to run hence there is nowhere to assign a static IP. Perhaps describe the higher level goal or what you’re trying to achieve, forget about IPs for now.

Comment: @MLu I edited my question. I think in my use-case Amazon Lightsail would be the best option. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you need a fixed, static *source IP addres* for your requests so that the API on the other side can whitelist it?

In that case yes, you’ll need a Lightsail or EC2 instance with static IP. Doing it serverless with Amplify would be too complicated.